# IntelliJ Idea 12 - Prevent program arguments from printing to the console

Tags: intellij-idea

For example, when I run mine.Test class, the first line of the console is this huge string, which means that the horizontal scrollbar of the console is too short. How can I stop this?

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7536 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\user\mydir\bin;C:\Users\user\mydir\lib\DTNConsoleConnection.jar;C:\Users\user\mydir\lib\ECLA.jar;C:\Users\user\mydir\jars\commons-math3-3.0.jar;C:\Users\user\mydir\jars\guava-12.0.1.jar;C:\Users\user\mydir\jars\mpj.jar;C:\Users\user\mydir\jars\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\user\mydir\jars\javageom-loweracc.jar;C:\Users\user\mydir\jars\jgrapht-jdk1.6.jar;C:\Users\user\mydir\jars\cplex.jar;C:\Users\user\mydir\jars\trove-3.0.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4\lib\junit-4.10.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain mine.Test
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click in the console on this line, choose **Fold lines like this**, configure the pattern for folding.

For me command line is folded by default when running unit tests and Java applications:

[image: folded command line]

Note that you can't turn off printing of the command line completely, you can only fold it.

To avoid the horizontal scrollbar you can also [enable soft wraps for the console](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/240/20130306102142.png).

Comment: Huh, nice trick, I didn't know this feature was configurable... thanks :)