# How can I remove/hide flags from Run in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I see the location of Java on my computer, but something about javaagent, Dfile, and classpath also show up every time I run a Java program:

[image]

How do I remove or hide it from being seen?

Here is the full line:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=64803:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/jeff/IdeaProjects/Java/out/production/Java Sample
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ Idea 12 - Prevent program arguments from printing to the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235470/intellij-idea-12-prevent-program-arguments-from-printing-to-the-console)